# Do the same fetch logic in different situation in one component

Tags: reactjs

I have a page where there are some components: Filters, Pagination and List (with some data from the server)

Filter component includes some selects elements, inputs, etc. and button "Find".
Pagination component includes page switchers buttons and a selector for a direct page and a select to choose how many elements we should show on a page

List component shows data from the server API

Also, I have a Parent component that has all of them and a common state. (I will simplify fetch logic, but the main point that it is sent a request with 2 objects as data)

```
const reducer = (options, newOptions) => ({
  ...options,
  ...newOptions
})

const ParentComponent = () => {
  const [filterOptions, setFilterOptions] = useReducer(
    reducer,
    {
      filterOption1: "",
      filterOption2: ""
      ....
    }
  )
  const [pagingOptions, setPagingOptions] = useReducer(
    reducer,
    {
      pageNumber: 1,
      elementsPerPage: 10,
      totalElement: 100
    }
  )

  const doFetch = () => {
    fetch('https://example.com', {
      body: {filters: filterOptions, paging: pagingOptions}
    })
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Filters
        filterOptions={filterOptions}
        onFilterOptionsChange={setFilterOptions}
        onFindClick={doFetch}
      />
      <Pagination
        pagingOptions={pagingOptions}
        onPagingOptionsChange={setPagingOptions}
      />
      <List data={data} />
    </>
  )
}
```

When we change some filters, data in filterOptions changes because we put *setFilterOptions* dispatch in to Filters component (I did not show what is inside Filters component, the main point is that we use `setFilterOptions({filterOption1: 'new_value'})` to change filterOptions when some filter select or input are changed) and when we click on the Find button inside Filters we use the method doFetch and do fetch with new values of filterOptions and default values of pagingOptions

After that, when data comes, we put it into List component and show it on a screen. Again I simplified it and write just `<List data={data} />`

My question is: How should I implement the logic for page changing. For Filters I have just one Find button to use fetch, but for paging, there are a lot of selectors and buttons that can change some of pagingOptions. And after we change a pagingOptions (a page or an elementsPerPage) I should immediately fire doFetch() method

I used useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
  doFetch()
}, [pagingOptions])
```

and see when pagingOptions changes then fire doFetch(), but eslint hooks warning told me that I should add doFetch in deps (I agree) but then it was a message in the console that doFetch should be in useCallback(), but if I wrapped doFetch() in useCallback() console told me that I should add filterOptions and pagingOptions in useCallback deps (because I use them in fetch) and after that, I got infinity loop of fetching api in network

Comment: if you want to call `doFetch` inside `useEffect` only. You can simply move the `doFetch` method inside your `useEffect` call

Comment: I think, It does not fit for me, I should use doFetch() in two cases when clicking the Find button inside Filters and when something in pagingOptions changes. If I move and write an implementation of doFetch() inside useEffect  I couldn't send doFetch method to Filters component. If leave doFetch() method and copy implementation of it inside useEffect I get copy of fetch you know like DRY.

Comment: Plus, if I implement doFetch() inside useEffect I should add to deps not only pagingOptions but filterOptions as well because it uses inside fetch, and it gets me that if one of filterOptions changes it would fetch to server, but in my case, for filters I should use doFetch when I ckick Find button